# Keyword to specify ambiguous/global namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, global

In this code snippet, found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).

```
void f() {
    d1++; // error: ambiguous ::d1 or D::d1?
    ::d1++; // OK <----**This one**
    D::d1++; // OK
    d2++; // OK, d2 is D::d2
    e++; // OK: e is E::e due to transitive using
    f(1); // error: ambiguous: D::f(int) or E::f(int)?
    f('a'); // OK: the only f(char) is D::f(char)
}
```

There is a piece of code used to specify a global namespace (`::d1++;`).

I have poked around and am having a hard time naming this "categorization"; and am looking for a better alternative. Is there any keywords that would fulfill this functionality, or are there any alternative approaches that are more explicit so that it may not be interpreted as a mistake?

The best guess I would have would to call this a non-declarative namespace. Any correction would be appreciated.

Comment: __Qualified Name Lookup__: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup  And `::` is the scope resolution operator.  Also read (and follow links) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup  Can't really answer your whole question here without reproducing too much text. And as @JesperJuhl says this is basic functionality.

Comment: Why would you worry that it would be considered a mistake? Any person who claims C++ competence should know that `::foo` means "`foo` in the global namespace".. `std::sqrt` is quite a different thing than `::sqrt` for example, but that shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: If you don't use global variables (which you shouldn't be) then you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The code is normal C++ code so it shouldn't be a problem.
If you still want to do the change you can:

1) use a macro

```
#define global(x) ::x
```

2)use an alias
`auto& global_d1 = ::d1;` to change the name so you won't have the collision